# Cardano-Cli Transactions with Assets Utxo

Tags: cardano-cli, transaction, native-assets

I am getting an error when trying to send a transaction with the following Utxos:

```
                             TxHash                                 TxIx        Amount
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3a197302622324ebda7b96b39bf566fb408309b8947e635675cbce94efb90bf6     1        2822751 lovelace + TxOutDatumNone
c84758dbea49a9bfd4ce143b074c2f89486027b0595e5e7ca6da5f32a63a3edf     0        5000000 lovelace + 1344000000 698a6ea0ca99f315034072af31eaac6ec11fe8558d3f48e9775aab9d.7444524950 + TxOutDatumNone
```

and here is the error:

```
Command failed: cardano-cli transaction submit                  --tx-file ./testnet/trial23_tx.signed                   --testnet-magic 1097911063
Command failed: transaction submit  Error: Error while submitting tx: ShelleyTxValidationError ShelleyBasedEraAlonzo (ApplyTxError [UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (UtxoFailure (ValueNotConservedUTxO (Value 7822751 (fromList [(PolicyID {policyID = ScriptHash "698a6ea0ca99f315034072af31eaac6ec11fe8558d3f48e9775aab9d"},fromList [("tDRIP",1344000000)])])) (Value 7822751 (fromList [])))))])
```

is this error due to the fact I am using a Utxo which holds an asset?
I was following this tutorial: https://developers.cardano.org/docs/stake-pool-course/handbook/create-simple-transaction/

is there a tutorial that would help me understand how to create a NOT simple transaction with Utxos + assets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is an example of a transaction i send from 2 TxHash, sending ADA + Token
remember, the summary of 2 tx-out must be equal to 2 tx-in.

cardano-cli transaction build-raw 
--fee {fee} 
--tx-in b98eb283dflkh4582402u40480253c23c0fc35e1a2bcf445e18#0 
--tx-in eebb2a5sldfjkdlkfjo485u30ruwldkfjs45346352126b220de8f6f#1 
--tx-out addr1qy4hewroi045398753987923oriwrio2u034urrt5rz0vdpmc8lzlpqcj0yznqwaelpl+2000000+"1 0fd9819234872935727sdf7027400df7hg077dc15.5692847553" 
--tx-out addr1v9uh244h55jk5k6jk4b2kn42kln53um+7049462+"8 0fd9819234872935727sdf7027400df7hg077dc15.5692847553" 
--out-file tx.raw

Comment: can one Utxo have more than one asset?

Comment: like:
`--tx-out "address+5000000 + 5 policyid.assethexname + 100 policyid2.assethexname2"` ?

Comment: yes for sure
, and you text it the correct way.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the Ada and asset in the output so it balances. Something like `--tx-out "address+5000000 + 5 policyid.assethexname"` with your remaining balance needed to balance the transaction.